# Error in SDF batch upload using cs-post-sdf: SSLException: Server Key

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

One of my Cloudsearch Upload Batch server is throwing this error message. I checked all configuration but not able to resolve it. Please help.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server key
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.throwSSLException(Handshaker.java:1274)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at com.a9.cloudsearch.service.util.CSDataUploader.sendData(CSDataUploader.java:184)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using Java 1.7.  It seems that Cloud Search Tools seem to require Java 1.6.

Check you Java Version number.